# substitution cipher case sensitive using c#

Tags: c#, encryption, substitution

i want to make encryption method that will accept uppercase and lower case both in plain text variable like ("Hello World) it is only accepting lower case letter please help me i want to amke 
its is working fine with only lowercase letters as input please help me

```
            using System;

        class SubstitutionCipher
        {
           static void Main()
           {
              string key = "jfkgotmyvhspcandxlrwebquiz";
              string plainText = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
              string cipherText = Encrypt(plainText, key);
              string decryptedText = Decrypt(cipherText, key);
              Console.WriteLine("Plain     : {0}", plainText);
              Console.WriteLine("Encrypted : {0}", cipherText);
              Console.WriteLine("Decrypted : {0}", plainText);
              Console.ReadKey();
           }
    //encryption method 
           static string Encrypt(string plainText, string key)
           {
              char[] chars = new char[plainText.Length];
              for(int i = 0; i < plainText.Length; i++)
              {
                 if (plainText[i] == ' ')
                 {
                    chars[i] = ' ';
                 }   
                 else
                 {
                    int j = plainText[i] - 97;
                    chars[i] = key[j];
                 }
              }
              return new string(chars);
           }
//decryption method
           static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string key)
           {
              char[] chars = new char[cipherText.Length];
              for(int i = 0; i < cipherText.Length; i++)
              {
                 if (cipherText[i] == ' ')
                 {
                    chars[i] = ' ';
                 }   
                 else
                 {
                    int j = key.IndexOf(cipherText[i]) - 97;
                    chars[i] = (char)j;
                 }
              }
              return new string(chars);
           } 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are subtracting 'a' and that's only for lower case characters. You should check if it's upper or lower case, and then subtract either A or a respectively. Also, you can just directly use 'a' or 'A' to get the `int` equivalent of the characters.

What I mean is use this for your `else` statements for Decrypt and Encrypt:

```
    static string Encrypt(string plainText, string key)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[plainText.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < plainText.Length; i++)
        {
            if (plainText[i] == ' ')
            {
                chars[i] = ' ';
            }
            else if (Char.IsUpper(plainText[i]))
            {
                int j = plainText[i] - 'A';
                chars[i] = key[j];
            }
            else
            {
                int j = plainText[i] - 'a';
                chars[i] = key[j];
            }
        }
        return new string(chars);

    static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string key)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[cipherText.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < cipherText.Length; i++)
        {
            if (cipherText[i] == ' ')
            {
                chars[i] = ' ';
            }
            else if (Char.IsUpper(cipherText[i]))
            {
                int j = key.IndexOf(cipherText[i]) - 'A';
                chars[i] = (char)j;
            }
            else
            {
                int j = key.IndexOf(cipherText[i]) - 'a';
                chars[i] = (char)j;
            }
        }
        return new string(chars);
    }
```

or short versions for Encrypt and Decrypt, respectively:

```
            else 
            {
                int j = Char.IsUpper(plainText[i]) ? plainText[i] - 'A' : plainText[i] - 'a';
                chars[i] = key[j];
            }

            else
            {
                int j = Char.IsUpper(cipherText[i]) ? key.IndexOf(cipherText[i]) - 'A' :  key.IndexOf(cipherText[i]) - 'a';
                chars[i] = (char)j;
            }
```

**EDIT:**

Okay I thought the algorithm was pretty much done and I had just fixed the part that would have caused an exception. However, you are:

a) Not taking into account which letter was capitalized and
b) Don't have a working Decryptor. (I thought it worked, but then your main method has the plaintext result as the decrypted message).

To fix your decryptor, you need to add a way on the Encryptor to store capital letters. You can be more sophisticated about it, but for now, we will just encrypt it as a capital letter on the cipher text.

```
    static string Encrypt(string plainText, string key)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[plainText.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < plainText.Length; i++)
        {
            if (plainText[i] == ' ')
            {
                chars[i] = ' ';
            }
            else 
            {
                int j = Char.IsUpper(plainText[i]) ? plainText[i] - 'A' : plainText[i] - 'a';
                chars[i] = Char.IsUpper(plainText[i]) ? Char.ToUpper(key[j]) : key[j];
            }
        }
        return new string(chars);
```

To Decrypt you should find it on the key as a lowercase character, but output as an uppercase character.

```
    static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string key)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[cipherText.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < cipherText.Length; i++)
        {
            if (cipherText[i] == ' ')
            {
                chars[i] = ' ';
            }
            else
            {
                int j = Char.IsUpper(cipherText[i]) ? key.IndexOf(Char.ToLower((char)cipherText[i])) + 'a' : key.IndexOf(cipherText[i]) + 'a';
                chars[i] = Char.IsUpper(cipherText[i]) ? Char.ToUpper((char)j) : (char)j;
            }
        }
        return new string(chars);
    }
```

Comment: after using your method the decrypt method is not working correctly what is the problem sir?
here is my code

Comment: @HoneyBuny apparently the decrypt function did not work to begin with. Hmph. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Sir its not again working :(
the encrypt working perfect but the decrypt method not still working its is giving result ,,,,,

Comment: This will work for all lower case keys. You have to adjust for upper case or mixed keys.

Comment: @HoneyBuny in short use your original `string key = "jfkgotmyvhspcandxlrwebquiz";`

Answer (score 0):

It's a intersting problem, especially when being stated in *general case*. So we have

1. Characters that are in key, and these ones should be ecnrypted (e.g. `a`, `j`)
2. Characters that are not in key,and these ones should be skipped (e.g. *space*)

To be a efficient, let's design a `Encryptor` \ `Decryptor` as `Dictionary<Char, Char>`, in order to do this we should sort the characters in the key and make correspondence of them;
e.g. for

```
  key        = "jfkgo"
  sorted key = "fgjko"
```

the pairs will be

```
  {j, f} // when encrypting "j" becomes "f", on decryption "f" turns into "j"
  {f, g}
  {k, j}
  {g, k}
  {o, o}
```

when read *left to right* we have an *encryptor*, when read *right to left* a *decryptor*:

```
private static Dictionary<Char, Char> Encryptor(String key) {
  Char[] data = key.ToArray();
  Char[] sorted = data.OrderBy(c => c).ToArray();

  return data
    .Zip(sorted, (plain, encrypted) => new {
         Plain = plain,
         Encrypted = encrypted
     })
    .ToDictionary(item => item.Plain, item => item.Encrypted);
}

// Note, that Decryptor is the same as Encryptor by for the last line
private static Dictionary<Char, Char> Decryptor(String key) {
  Char[] data = key.ToArray();
  Char[] sorted = data.OrderBy(c => c).ToArray();

  return data
    .Zip(sorted, (plain, encrypted) => new {
      Plain = plain,
      Encrypted = encrypted
    })
    .ToDictionary(item => item.Encrypted, item => item.Plain);
}
```

Now, it's easy to implement Encrypt and Decrypt methods

```
private static String Encrypt(String source, String key) {
  var dict = Encryptor(key);

  StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder(source.Length);

  Char sub;

  foreach (var ch in source)
    if (dict.TryGetValue(ch, out sub))
      Sb.Append(sub);
    else
      Sb.Append(ch);

  return Sb.ToString();
}

 // Note, that Decryptor is the same as Encryptor by for the first line
private static String Decrypt(String source, String key) {
  var dict = Decryptor(key);

  StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder(source.Length);

  Char sub;

  foreach (var ch in source)
    if (dict.TryGetValue(ch, out sub))
      Sb.Append(sub);
    else
      Sb.Append(ch);

  return Sb.ToString();
}
```

A small test

```
 // For test, let capital letters mmimic the small ones
 string key = "jfkgotmyvhspcandxlrwebquiz" + "jfkgotmyvhspcandxlrwebquiz".ToUpper();

 string plainText = "The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog!";
 string cipherText = Encrypt(plainText, key);
 string decryptedText = Decrypt(cipherText, key);

 Console.WriteLine("Plain     : {0}", plainText);
 Console.WriteLine("Encrypted : {0}", cipherText);
 Console.WriteLine("Decrypted : {0}", plainText);
```